# Javascript Fetch Requests

Tags: javascript, fetch, flux

I currently have two data files. The first is just a list of the projects I'm concerned with, i.e.

**PROJECT_DATA_LIST**

```
{"id": "1a", "name": "project1"},
{"id": "2b", "name": "project2"}
```

The second is a list of data for each project more specifically:

**PROJECT_DATA**

```
var project1 = [
{
    group: "Alpha",
    data: [
        {
            label: "Accounting",
            data: [
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:40:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:20 AM", "2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Engineering",
            data: [
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Marketing",
            data: [
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
            ]
        },
    ]
},
{
    group: "Beta",
    data: [
        {
            label: "Accounting",
            data: [
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:20 AM", "2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Engineering",
            data: [
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:40 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:42:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:42:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:42:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Marketing",
            data: [
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
var project2 = [
    {
        group: "Alpha",
        data: [
            {
                label: "Accounting",
                data: [
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:40:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:20 AM", "2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Engineering",
                data: [
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Marketing",
                data: [
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        group: "Beta",
        data: [
            {
                label: "Accounting",
                data: [
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:20 AM", "2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Engineering",
                data: [
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:40 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:42:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:42:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:42:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Marketing",
                data: [
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:40:40 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                    {timeRange: ["2018-02-26 11:41:00 AM", "2018-02-26 11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I am trying to use the first file as a key to fetch data for a specific project. So, for "project1" from the first file return **project1** data from the second file. I know I need to use a javascript fetch/then to accomplish this. Something like:

```
fetch(project_list)
    .then( function (project_data) {

//fetch the data for each project
    for(var project of project_data){

        //fetch data for specific project
        fetch(project_data_list).then(function( project_data ){

            //add project data to run data store
            store.add(...)
        })

    }

})
```

But, I mean that's obviously wrong (and incomplete). Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

I'm using a FLUX design pattern, hence the store.add.

Comment: why dont you fetch both seperate, store them in objects and compare them here. i dont see the point of a fetch in a for each.

Comment: Could be easier to start if you keep datas in same file. I see no any advantage to separate those yet. Why you need to separate datas?

Comment: I can't combine the data sets. 

I think Paulquappe is closer to what I need. Ultimately, I need to be able to pull out (per project) id and all of its associated data